# SQL Server need to find suppliers who supply the most different products

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by

I have two tables I need information from, `Products` and `Suppliers`. Both these tables have a `SupplierID` column I am trying to use to join them together to retrieve the right info.

The output I need is `SupplierID` and `ContactName` from the `Suppliers` table. The correct output should contain only two suppliers, so I attempted something like this, but ran into a conversion error converting nvarchar value to a data type int. I am not supposed to count how many products they supply but aggregate functions seem like the best method to me.

```
SELECT TOP 2 ContactName, COUNT(Products.SupplierID) AS Supply
FROM Products 
LEFT JOIN Suppliers ON Suppliers.ContactName = Products.SupplierID
GROUP BY Products.SupplierID, Suppliers.ContactName
ORDER BY Supply;
```

I have tried many different queries but none will work. I am confused on how to join these tables without running into errors. All the products have a unique ProductID as well. The correct output should look something like this:

```
   7     John Smith
  12     John Sample
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Both these tables have a SupplierID column I am trying to use to join them together to retrieve the right info

If so, you should be joining on that column accross tables.

Also, it is a good practice to use table aliases and prefix each column with the table it belongs to.

Another remark is that if you want suppliers that sell the *most* different products, then you want to order by descending count (not ascending).

Finally, if you want to `left join`, then you should start from the suppliers and then bring in the products, not the other way around.

Consider:

```
select top 2 
    s.SupplierID,
    s.ContactName, 
    COUNT(*) as Supply
from Suppliers s
left join Products p on p.SupplierID = s.SupplierID
group by s.SupplierID, s.ContactName
order by Supply desc;
```

Comment: This certainly worked and I will mark as correct, but could you explain how the COUNT(*) here knew to count the number of instances of SupplierID? A where clause was not specified so I am just curious. Does it have to do with the left join?

Answer (score 0):

You're currently joining on two different fields:

```
on Suppliers.ContactName = Products.SupplierID
```

Presumably this should be as follows?

```
on Suppliers.SupplierID = Products.SupplierID
```